# HISTTIMEFORMAT and deleting matching history entries

Tags: bash, shell, command-history

I would like to delete all history entries matching a certain string. I found
[this method](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/57925):

```
grep -v searchstring "$HISTFILE" > /tmp/history
mv /tmp/history "$HISTFILE"
```

but it does not account for the HISTTIMEFORMAT comments, for example:

```
#1517681911
echo 1
#1517681918
echo 2
#1517681931
echo 3
```

If I wanted to remove "echo 2", the preceding comment would need to be removed
as well. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed is your friend (awk could do it as well), you may use this code (assuming every line matched indeed has a time line):

```
sed '$!N;/echo 2/!P;D' "$HISTFILE" > /tmp/history
```

or to do it directly in the history file:

```
sed -i '$!N;/echo 2/!P;D' "$HISTFILE"
```

The example you have will become this:

```
#1517681911
echo 1
#1517681931
echo 3
```

---

A more restrictive match: only erase actual time lines before the pattern (match lines that have one field that is a # followed by ten digits)

```
awk -vp="echo 2" ' {b=$0};b~p{next}
                   NF=1 && b~/#[0-9]{10}/{a=b;next}
                   {print(a RS b)}
                 ' "$HISTFILE"
```